# Free memory in c++ (armadillo)

Tags: c++, free, armadillo

I want to free memory after using an object ('ii', in the following program) in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
    cx_mat ii(2,2,fill::eye);
    cout << ii <<endl;
    free (ii);
    return 0;
}
```

But after compiling, I encounter to the following error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘arma::cx_mat {aka arma::Mat<std::complex<double> >}’ to ‘void*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void free(void*)’
```

can any body guide me?

Comment: `ii` has "automatic storage duration", so its memory is released when the function returns. If your book or tutorial suggested that you do it manually, get a new one. If you haven't got a book, get one.

Comment: You seem to be lacking some very basic knowledge. You should read a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

```
cx_mat ii(2,2,fill::eye);
```

That's allocated on the stack, you can't free it, it will be destroyed when your program exits the scope.

http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can *only* `free` pointers holding an address returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. Nothing else. In particular, no matrices.

You also should not need to use `free` in C++, ever.

In your case, you do not need to do anything to free the memory, the destructor of the matrix will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the error you're getting is because you're not passing a pointer to the function.

However, [free requires](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) that you pass a pointer that has been returned by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, otherwise undefined behavior occurs.

The memory of your object will be freed when your function returns, or exits.